# How to uninstall WMWare Player when HyperV is installed?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, vmware-player

I installed WMWare VMPlayer, then installed the HyperV role.  I am now trying to uninstall the VMPlayer, but it won't let me:

[image]

What can I do to uninstall VMPlayer (short of uninstalling HyperV)?

Comment: Does VMWare Player show up in 'Programs and Features' ?

Comment: @Ethabelle Yes, it does.  That's where I am uninstalling it from.

Comment: Why not just uninstall the Hyper-V role, uninstall VMware Player, reinstall the Hyper-V role, and be done with it?

Comment: @joeqwerty Because I spent a ton of time getting HyperV into the right state and don't want to risk losing it.

Comment: sounds like you'll need to hack the registry to kinda remove the app.

Answer (score 0):

May this post could help:

http://communities.vmware.com/message/1713424#1713424

```
only chance :add a bootoption to the server so it can start with disabled HyperV



At the command prompt, type the following:    
bcdedit /copy {default} /d "No Hypervisor"
The above command should say: The entry was successfully copied to {guid}. Copy that guid to the clipboard including the curly braces.
Now, type the following command:    
bcdedit /set {guid_hvoff} hypervisorlaunchtype off
In the above command, replace {guid_hvoff} with what you copied in step 2. The above command just sets a property in the boot entry that will not load the hypervisor on boot.
```

then reboot into No HyperV Option and uninstall